# Symfony2 - Check if "application/json" is supported in Accept HTTP header

Tags: json, http, symfony

I'm using the Symfony2 framework for building a REST API,

I send the response to my clients using "application/json",

How can I check if applcation/json is supported in their HTTP request header?

Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check the [`getAcceptableContentTypes`](http://api.symfony.com/2.5/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/Request.html#method_getAcceptableContentTypes) method on the [request](http://api.symfony.com/2.5/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/Request.html) object.

```
$acceptsJsonContent = in_array('application/json', $request->getAcceptableContentTypes());
```

Answer (score 0):

When your client requests a response in an exact format, it should specify an `Accept:` header, see the [HTTP/1.1 spec](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html).

Answer (score 0):

The header of the `json` request should be like this.

`headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'}`

Back in controller you can filter the request to see whether it's coming through a xml/http content. (Such as Ajax)

```
if($request->isXmlHttpRequest())
{

    $result = json_encode($json);

    return new Response($result , 200 , array( 'Content-Type' => 'application/json' ));
}
```

Hope this helps.

Cheers!

Comment: Checking for `$request->isXmlHttpRequest()` is ok if your Javascript library adds the header `X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest` (most do) but is no good for APIs. I would use the `Accept` header (because that's its purpose) and in Symfony the method `getAcceptableContentTypes()`, as stated in @devsheeep's response